# request for member 'append' in 'a' , which is of non class type 'int'

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, max, unsigned-integer

im new to programming so my doubts are pretty sily maybe.
so when im trying to solve a challenge in which i have to form the biggest number from the digits in array.
so i created a compare function and passes in to the sort function. in compare function im check if a+b is bigger than b+a and vice versa.
but the compiler shows the error stating request for member non class type.

i actually dont have any idea on how to solve this, i tried googling stuff but didnt got my solution.
i found the similar solution but they are doing it with string. can it  be done with array.

```
int myCompare( int a, int b){


    int ab= a.append(b);
    int ba= b.append(a);

    if(ab>ba){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

}

void biggestnum(int arr[], int n){

    if(n==0 || n==1){
        return;
    }

    sort(arr,arr+n, myCompare);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

so if the given array is {54, 546, 548, 60};
the result should be 6054854654.

Comment: If you don't understand why you can't use member functions on primitive types (like `int`) then you need to go back to your text-books, tutorials or classes because there's something you missed.

Comment: What is `int ab= a.append(b);` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar fundamental type `int` does not have methods. So these records

```
a.append(b);
b.append(a);
```

are invalid.

It seems using such a construction like this

```
a.append(b)
```

you are trying to convert an integer to an object of the class `std::string`. However if `a` and `b` were objects of the type `std::string` there is no sense to append one object to another. It is enough to compare the original strings.

It seems what you are trying to achieve is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool myCompare( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    std::string s1 = std::to_string( a );
    std::string s2 = std::to_string( b );

    auto n = std::minmax( { s1.size(), s2.size() } );

    int result = s1.compare( 0, n.first, s2, 0, n.first );

    return ( result > 0 ) || 
           ( result == 0 && 
           ( ( s1.size() < n.second && s2[n.first] < s1[0] ) || 
             ( s2.size() < n.second && s2[0] < s1[n.first] ) ) );
}    

int main() 
{
    unsigned int a[] = { 54, 546, 548, 60 };

    std::sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), myCompare );

    std::string s;

    for ( const auto &item : a )
    {
        s += std::to_string( item );
    }

    unsigned long long int value = std::stoull( s );

    std::cout << "The maximum number is " << value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The maximum number is 6054854654
```

if the result number can be too big to fit into an object of the type unsigned long long int then you can remove the statement

```
    unsigned long long int value = std::stoull( s );
```

and just output the result string as

```
    std::cout << "The maximum number is " << s << '\n';
```

Comment: I think you missed the purpose of the assignment, which is to find the largest _lexical concatenation_ of all the numbers found in the array. Just sorting the array by each element's numerical magnitude doesn't necessarily achieve that. Then again, as far as I can tell, neither does the OP's solution!

Comment: Your proposed solution with a single multiplication by ten doesn't seem right, either. It would be if each element were only single-digit, as the question's prose suggests, but the given example data discounts that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As it follows from the question there is an array of digits that is needed to be sorted in the descending order and nothing more.

Comment: Mate it literally says _"the given array is `{54, 546, 548, 60}`"_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh I did not pay attention to this.:)

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense. Much simpler than my solution!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow very thanks foryour response. I did tried your code. i would like to inform that most of the things you used in the program are of high level and as i said im just a beginner, but anyway thanks. also your code is giving me '5465485460' as output. whereas the expected output is 6054854654. so i dont know where the issue came as i said im just a newbie. but still thanks for your support.

Comment: @AndroTech I am sorry. There was a typo in this expression return ( result > 1 ) There must be return ( result > 0 ). I already updated the code in the answer.